# Instantiate and set to parent of a sub gameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a multi level gameObject hierarchy that is defined as below (in the picture). The below script I attach to GameObject `Main`. How do I instantiate a gameObject and set it child of gameObject `05` by just searching for the string inside the `Main` hierarchy.

```
public string ParentObjName = "05";
 public void Instantiate () {
        
            GameObject 06 = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath ("Assets/Resources/06.prefab", typeof (GameObject)) as GameObject;
            GameObject go = (GameObject) GameObject.Instantiate (06 , Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
            go.transform.parent = ParentObjName.GameObject.transform; //Add to GameObject 05
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reference to `Main` already then all you need is [`Transform.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html) recursive like e.g.

```
public static class TransformExtensions
{
    public static Transform TryFindRecursive(this Transform transform, string childName, out Transform result)
    {
        // Searches for childName in the first level children of the current transform
        result = transform.Find(childName);

        // I we found one return immediately
        if(result)
        {
            return true;
        }

        // Otherwise iterate through the first level children of the current transform
        foreach(var child in transform)
        {
            // Search for childName recursive
            if(TryFindRecursive(child, childName, out result))
            {
                // If we found one return
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then assuming you somewhere have the reference

```
Transform MainReference;
```

you could use it like e.g.

```
if(!MainReference.TryFindRecursive(ParentObjName, out var parentTransform)
{
    Debug.LogError($"No object found under \"{MainReference.name}\" that is called \"{ParentObjName}\"!");
    return;
}

go.transform.parent = parentTransform;
```

In general of course you should store this reference and not everytime run this recursive search over and over again!

Answer (score 0):

If your gameobject `Main` is a prefab or if it's already existing on your scene at editor time you better make a reference to your transform container `05`

```
public Transform Container05;
```

It remove the fact Unity must search a specific transform it already have the reference.

If it's not possible (for example you are instantiate Main and its children on runtime) you can search for a named child like this:

```
Transform container = GameObject.Find("05").transform;
```

It work only if you have only one gameobject named "05" otherwise you will get one of them.

The last way is to recursively search for your child into the hierarchy.
See derHugo answer for a good recurcsively implementation.

And at the end when you instantiate your gameobject you can pass the parent directly and avoid a cast by using the generic `Instantiate<T>` method.

```
Transform container05 = FindTransformByNameRecursively("05",transform);
GameObject prefab06 = UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Resources/06.prefab", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
var new06 = Instantiate<GameObject>(prefab06, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, container05);
```